# Nattable filtering empty strings

Tags: nattable

I'm using NatTable with a filter. It works perfect, except when there are cells with empty strings (Strings with length 0). When I set the filter to the empty string, the result contains everything.
I changed the textmatchingmode but that didn't help.

How should I change the filter so that it can filter empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you will need to implement a custom IFilterStrategy that uses an empty String as filter criteria. The default implementation is using an empty String and null to remove the filter, since it does not interprete them as valid filter value.